# PHP: Conversion String to integer without deleting leading zeroes

Tags: php, int

I've got an input field which contains the file mode used for chmod.

If I use this, it is used as string, so it fails. It I convert it to int (intval()), it deletes the leading zero (0777 => 777) and fails again. If I use it like this:

```
$int = intval($input);
$finished = 0 . $int;
```

This also fails because `is_int($finished)` is false.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leading zeroes are a nonexistent concept for integers, because they are mathematically insignificant. In decimal notation, the integer `0777` is simply and exactly equal to `777`.

But if you're trying to convert `"0777"` in octal notation to its integer counterpart (`511` as a decimal) for use with `chmod()`, you can use `octdec($input)`. The function takes a string and spits out an integer, doing exactly what it says on the tin.

Of course, be sure you perform validation first, e.g. by using a regex. You don't want to hand a global or invalid flag to `chmod()` and potentially expose your sensitive files and folders to the public.

Comment: This answer is correct. However, if you are just doing this to validate input, a regular expression may be more useful because it will actually be able to detect invalid data, as opposed to just converting invalid data to some "arbitrary" integer.

Comment: @Matthew: Sanitization can be done as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049245/php-conversion-string-to-integer-without-deleting-leading-zeroes/8049466#8049466

Answer (score 2):

You're using an input field to obtain `$input`. That means the value is a string then.

You're looking for an [octal number](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) inside that value. [`intval`](http://php.net/intval) is not handling strings as octal numbers.

[`chmod`](http://php.net/chmod) expects the `$mode` parameter to be an integer value.

To convert a string containing an octal number, you can use the [`octdec`](http://php.net/octdec) function:

```
$int = octdec($value); # '0777' -> 511
```

So you might want to validate the input and check if it does qualify as an octal number as well, for example by converting it again with [`decoct`](http://php.net/decoct) and testing if it results in the same:

```
$valid = "0".decoct($int) === $value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to check input with preg_match(). refer below code.

```
if(preg_match("/[^0-9.]/", $input)) 
{
    return false;
}
else
{
  -- Some Code Here --
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to solve, an integer type can't start with 0 unless its equal to 0. 0777 is equal to 777 by value, Usually theres no problem setting a permission as 777, the system will know to treat it as 0777.

If you MUST pass a leading zero, it must be as a string (e.g. `'0'.$finished`)

Shai.

Answer (score 0):

When you use function 0 . $int; php understand that is a operation add two string. So result 
$finished  will be a string. try to use function number_format to solve.